# What do the backslashes do in this Gosu code?

Tags: jvm, gosu

I'm not too deep in Gosu, so this code confused me. I've googled, etc., but to no avail. What are the backslashes doing in this snippet?

```
GET_STUFF.execute(\ -> {
      var gig = withPackagedGig(request.id, request.signature, \ k -> {
        k.addItem("Log_RetrievedGig");
        return k;
      });
      myObj = toObj(gig);
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line continuation characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514873/line-continuation-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: It doesn't look like a java code

Comment: @the_storyteller, but there wouldn't be characters *after* the line continuation character, would there?

Comment: Yeah, this wouldn't compile in java 8 (obviously not 8, `var`), but I'm not sure the backslash would work here as intended in pure java. It would qualify as an illegal character

Comment: This is not valid Java syntax in any Java version so far. Something else must be processing it before the compiler and using the backslashes to escape the spaces for some reason.

Comment: I misread the question, thinking it was Javascript. That _is_ valid Javascript.

Comment: @Michael, good to know. I'll go back to the person that provided it. Thanks.

Comment: @the_storyteller, good to know. What would the backslashes do in this code if it were javascript?

Comment: @JonathanM Look at question the_storyteller linked.

Comment: @JonathanM, then it would be a line continuation character (see possible duplicate answer.) It isn't necessary for line continuation, but is valid syntax.

Comment: @the_storyteller, ah, yes, I thought you were referring to a different use. It definitely could be line continuation in js, but it wouldn't make sense for there to be characters after the slash in that case. I'm guessing this is somehow corrupted Java (as the provider said it was Java, and it has typed variables elsewhere, along with annotations).

Comment: Thanks for your help, all.

Comment: Which version of Java? The use of `var` means it's either Java 10 (very new), or it's Javascript.

Comment: @the_storyteller, I'll have to get that from the provider.

Comment: As you all suspected, it's not pure Java, but a custom variant called Gosu: https://gosu-lang.github.io/. I've updated the tags.

Comment: Sorry for the wild goose chase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash is just part of the syntax of a [block](https://gosu-lang.github.io/docs.html#blocks).

`\ -> {` is equivalent to Java's `() -> {` - a lambda taking no parameters.

`\ k -> {` is equivalent to Java's `k -> {` - a lambda taking one parameter whose type is inferred.

Comment: Lol, you and I were working to close this out at the same time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This question was originally posted when thinking the code was Java. Upon discovering it is Gosu, the answer is given by the [docs](https://gosu-lang.github.io/docs.html#blocks).

Lambdas in Gosu are set off by the backslash.